# Derangement problem!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion, derangements

Is the solution of the problem, in how many ways can the digits $$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$$

be arranged so that no even digit is in its original position, is $5!D_5$.

Where $D_n$ = $n! \left( 1-\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+....+(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{n!} \right)$ and denotes derangement number.

Here we find expression of $D_n$ using inclusion exclusion principle.

$P_i$: $i^{th}$ object is at it's place.

$N(P_i)$ Number of object having property $P_i$

so we have to find $N(P_1P_2....P_n)$

Comment: I feel it's worth pointing out that Brian's answer shows that $5!D_5 = 120\cdot44 = 5280$ is _not_ actually the correct answer to the original problem; instead, that value counts the number of arrangements of the digits that leave all the odd digits in odd positions and all the even digits in even positions (but none in its original position).  It misses arrangements like 1203564897 that 'shuffle' the positions of the odd and even digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We count the permutations in which no even number ends up in its original position (*good* permutations) by dividing into cases.

There are $5$ odd numbers. Perhaps $0$ end up their original positions, or perhaps exactly $1$, or perhaps exactly $2$, and so on up to $5$.

There are $D_{10}$ good permutations in which $0$ odds end up in their original position.

For good permutations with exactly $1$ odd in its original position, the odd can be chosen in $\binom{5}{1}$ ways. Everybody else must move, giving a total of $\binom{5}{1}D_9$.

For exactly $2$ odd in their original positions, the odds can be chosen in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. Everybody else must move, giving a total of $\binom{5}{2}D_8$.

And so on (three more cases). The total count is
$$\sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{5}{k}D_{10-k}.$$

Answer (score 9):

This can be done with an [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) argument. There are $10!$ permutations altogether. For each set of $r$ even digits there are $(10-r)!$ permutations that leave that set of digits fixed (and possibly others as well), and there are $\binom5r$ sets of $r$ even digits. Thus, the number of permutations leaving no even digit fixed is

$$\sum_{r=0}^5(-1)^r\binom5r(10-r)!=10!-5\cdot9!+10\cdot8!-10\cdot7!+5\cdot6!-5!=2,170,680\;.$$

**Added:** In terms of the notation in [this answer to your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332971/12042),

$$s_r=\binom5r(10-r)!\;,$$

so $$S(x)=\sum_{r=0}^5s_rx^r=\sum_{r=0}^5\binom5r(10-r)!x^r$$ and

$$E(x)=S(x-1)=\sum_{r=0}^5s_rx^r=\sum_{r=0}^5\binom5r(10-r)!(x-1)^r\;.$$

We want

$$e_0=E(0)=\sum_{r=0}^5\binom5r(10-r)!(-1)^r\;.$$

Comment: Here 2170680 is required answer.But how can we calculate our answer in terms of $D_n$.

Comment: @stranger001: I’m not sure that we can, at least in any straightforward way: we’re deranging only a subset of the digits, and that changes things a lot.

Comment: so we use $D_n$ directly in cases when derangement of whole set is done???

Comment: @stranger001: Yes. For instance, in this problem if you were counting permutations that derange the even digits **within their original places** and do the same thing with the odd digits, you’d get $D_5^2$, because you’re deranging two whole sets independently.