# Permuation & combination on finding number of ways lid can be wrongly placed

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

There are 5 bottles of sherry and each have their respective caps. 
If you are asked to put the correct cap to the correct bottle then how many ways are there so that not a single cap is on the correct bottle?

My approach:

first bottle has 4 ways (excluding the correct cap)
second bottle has 3 ways (excluding the correct cap + already used cap)
Thir bottle has 2 ways
fourth bottle has 1 way
fifth bottle has 1 way

So totally 4*3*2 = 24 ways.

But answer 44. Pls explain the approach

Comment: possible duplicate of [Derangement problem!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334755/derangement-problem)

Comment: Please see Wikipedia, *derangements*. A careful count will show that there are $44$ in this case.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yea, thats what I asked for! Pls explain how to make that count..

Comment: @Unknown:  He has shown how to do so in the answer I linked to.  It is also in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: The question linked to is somewhat more complicated. There are other MSE answers that deal specifically with $D_5$ using basic counting techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second bottle might have four choices if the one used for the first was the one intended for the second bottle.  You are looking at the number of [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  For $n$ items it is the closest natural to $\frac {n!}e$