# how many ways n number can be placed in first m position exactly k number unchanged?

Tags: combinatorics

### how many ways n number can be placed in  first m position  exactly k number unchanged?

Consider this sequence {1, 2, 3 ... N}, as an initial sequence of first N natural numbers. You can rearrange this sequence in many ways. There will be a total of N! arrangements. You have to calculate the number of arrangement of first N natural numbers, where in first M positions; exactly K numbers are in their initial position.

Comment: I don't see where $M$ comes into play, seems the answer should just depend on $N$ and $K$.

Comment: if n=5, m=3 and  k=2 then the arrangement will be 1 2 5 4 3 , 1  4 3 5 2 , 5 2 3 1 4. that means in  first 3 position  two will be unchanged 1 2, * 2 3, 1* 3  and rest  one will not be there original positions. but the another 2 positions (n-m) all numbers may be or may not be  there position . so the answer will depend on m obviously.  @Gregory Grant

Comment: I see, $M$ comes into play because of the requirement of "*exactly* $K$ numbers"

Comment: exactly k numbers will be there original positions from first m positions. for example if m=3 and k=2 then exactly two numbers will be there original positions from first 3 positions. like ,{ 1 , 2 (other than 3)}, {1 , (other than 2),3 } , {  (other than 1), 2,3} .@Gregory Grant

Comment: main difference is rest of first (m-k) numbers will not be there original positions but other, n-m may be there original positions or may not be there original positions

Comment: It seems tedious, and perhaps we need inclusion-exclusion principle to count precisely...

Answer (score 1):

First, choose which $K$ of the first $M$ spaces have the number unchanged: ${M \choose K}$.

Then, the remaining $M-K$ spaces in the first $M$ must move elsewhere, but everything else is fair game.  Following the derangement methodology [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334755/derangement-problem), the total number of arrangements becomes:

$$F(N,M,K) = _MC_K \cdot \sum_{L=0}^{N-M} {{N-M} \choose L} D_{N-K-L}$$

where $D_n$ is the derangement number.

Comment: its clear now....